# Application Updates Not Initiating

Tags: c#, winforms, updates, startup, shortcut

I have a C# WinForms application that initializes in the taskbar on startup using a shortcut in the user's startup folder:

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string startupFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Startup);
        string shortcutAddress = startupFolder + @"\NotifyNinja.lnk";
        if (checkBox1.Checked)
        {
            if (!io.File.Exists(shortcutAddress))
            {
                WshShell shell = new WshShell();
                IWshShortcut shortcut = (IWshShortcut)shell.CreateShortcut(shortcutAddress);
                shortcut.Description = "A startup shortcut. If you delete this shortcut from your computer, Notify.exe will not launch on Windows Startup"; // set the description of the shortcut
                shortcut.WorkingDirectory = Application.StartupPath; /* working directory */
                shortcut.TargetPath = Application.ExecutablePath; /* path of the executable */
                shortcut.Save(); // save the shortcut 
            }
            else
            {
                io.File.Delete(shortcutAddress);
                WshShell shell = new WshShell();
                IWshShortcut shortcut = (IWshShortcut)shell.CreateShortcut(shortcutAddress);
                shortcut.Description = "A startup shortcut. If you delete this shortcut from your computer, Notify.exe will not launch on Windows Startup"; // set the description of the shortcut
                shortcut.WorkingDirectory = Application.StartupPath; /* working directory */
                shortcut.TargetPath = Application.ExecutablePath; /* path of the executable */
                shortcut.Save(); // save the shortcut 
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (io.File.Exists(shortcutAddress))
            {
                io.File.Delete(shortcutAddress);
            }
        }
    }
```

This works perfectly, but I have made several updates to my application since first publishing it and my users do not seem to receive them. My updates are set to:

1. Check after application begins
2. Every 7 days
3. No minimum version required

Upon further testing it seems that if I remove the startup shortcut, close the program, and re-open it then the updates take effect.

Any thoughts on how I could trigger the updates for this auto-starting program?

Comment: Is checkbox1 checked?  Make sure checkbox1 is really checkbox 1 and not checkbox 2.

Comment: Yes, the checkbox is working perfectly. My concern is that the startup functionality is inadvertently disabling the application updates.

Comment: How do you publish your application? If you use clickonce you just need to configure those features

Comment: Yes, I do use clickonce. I also have the associated update features enabled. The problem is that they do not seem to be doing anything. I use the same configuration for other applications that do not automatically start and the updates work fine.

Comment: Check to see if the datetime of the lnk file changes.  If it doesn't change then there is an error in the code.

Comment: On my CPU the shortcut updates correctly, but if the updates are not taking effect on the user CPUs then it's likely not. Do you have any thoughts on why the updates might not be triggering on the user CPUs?

Comment: I was able to confirm that the shortcut date/timestamp does update.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is not a suitable method to initiate the clickonce updates when automatically starting your application with Windows, so I had to call the updates programmatically:

```
UpdateCheckInfo info = null;
        if (Directory.Exists(@"F:\..."))
        {
            if (ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
            {
                ApplicationDeployment ad = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment;

                try
                {
                    info = ad.CheckForDetailedUpdate();

                }
                catch { }
                if (info.UpdateAvailable)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        ad.Update();
                        Application.Restart();
                    }
                    catch { }
                }
            }
        }
```